# Changing one element of string in hashtable in C#

Tags: c#, string, hashtable

I have to write a program which use hashtable and the keys/values are input by the user. In the program, I have to output all the keys, however if any key starts with small 'a', I have to make it start with a big 'A'. I have a problem in the last step.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Vnesete kluc");
                string kluc = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Vnesete podatok");
                string podatok = Console.ReadLine();
                hashtable.Add(kluc, podatok);
            }

            foreach (string klucevi in hashtable.Keys)
            {
                if (klucevi[0] == 'a')
                {
                    klucevi[0] = 'A';
                }
                Console.WriteLine(klucevi);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error on the line where I'm converting the first element of the string if it's 'a' to 'A'.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Error: Property of indexer 'string.this[int]' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

Comment: That's because strings are immutable. And you can't change the key like that.

Comment: Remark: Do use the type-safe `new Dictionary<string, string>()` instead of `new Hashtable()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't dynamically change keys. Most simple approach is check the key **before** you add to the collection:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Vnesete kluc");
    string kluc = Console.ReadLine();
    if (kluc.StartsWith("a"))
        kluc = "A" + kluc.Substring(1);
    Console.WriteLine("Vnesete podatok");
    string podatok = Console.ReadLine();
    hashtable.Add(kluc, podatok);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with hash tables. You have a compilation error, because in .NET strings are immutable.

Secondly, and this is unrelated, a foreach loop variable cannot be assigned to.

So, instead of

```
foreach (string klucevi in *whatever*)
{
    if (klucevi[0] == 'a')
    {
        klucevi[0] = 'A';
    }
    Console.WriteLine(klucevi);
}
```

use

```
foreach (string klucevi in *whatever*)
{
    var temp = klucevi;

    if (temp[0] == 'a')
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(temp);

        sb[0] = 'A';

        temp = sb.ToString();
    }
    Console.WriteLine(temp);
}
```

don't forget to include a `using System.Text;` declaration.

UPDATE:
The aswer above shows you a generic way to modify a string in .NET, not just to replace one character.

Furthermore, some people have raised concerns about the efficiency of the approach. They are mistaken. More information in this execelent article on [Strings Undocumented](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3377/Strings-UNDOCUMENTED).

UPDATE 2:
I like being challenged. While it is totally irrelevant for the question at hand, a discussion has emmerged about the efiiciency of using a StringBuilder, compared to using `"A" + temp.Substring(1)`. Because I like facts, and I assume some readers would agree, I ran a little benchmark.

I ran the tests on a 64 bit Windows 7 box with .NET 4.5 as both a 32 and a 64 bit process. It turns out that the StringBuilder approach is always faster than the alternative, by about 20%. Memory usage is approximately the same. YMMV.

For those who care to repeat the test, here's the source code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int length = 50; length <= 51200; length = length * 2)
        {
            string input = new string(' ', length);

            // warm up
            PerformTest(input, 1);

            // actual test
            PerformTest(input, 100000);
        }
    }

    static void PerformTest(string input, int iterations)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();

        int gcRuns = GC.CollectionCount(0);

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = iterations; i > 0; i--)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);

            sb[0] = 'A';

            input = sb.ToString();
        }

        long ticksWithStringBuilder = sw.ElapsedTicks;
        int gcRunsWithStringBuilder = GC.CollectionCount(0) - gcRuns;

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForFullGCComplete();

        gcRuns = GC.CollectionCount(0);

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = iterations; i > 0; i--)
        {
            input = "A" + input.Substring(1);
        }

        long ticksWithConcatSubstring = sw.ElapsedTicks;
        int gcRunsWithConcatSubstring = GC.CollectionCount(0) - gcRuns;

        if (iterations > 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                "String length: {0, 5} With StringBuilder {1, 9} ticks {2, 5} GC runs, alternative {3, 9} ticks {4, 5} GC Runs, speed ratio {5:0.00}", 
                input.Length, 
                ticksWithStringBuilder, gcRunsWithStringBuilder, 
                ticksWithConcatSubstring, gcRunsWithConcatSubstring, 
                ((double)ticksWithStringBuilder) / ((double)ticksWithConcatSubstring));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't change a `foreach iteration` variable. `klucevi = sb.ToString();` won't compile. Even if it did, it won't change the key value in the hashtable.

Comment: That's a very ugly (not to mention inefficient) way to change first character of a string. Plus, what the first comment says.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM Yep, I noticed that too late. I have updated my answer already.

Comment: @ShadowWizard What makes you think this is ineffcient? My guess is that it is more efficient than the obvious `"A" + temp.Substring(1)`, because it performs less memory allocations. It certainly is more versatile.

Comment: You create whole new StringBuilder just for the minor task of replacing single character. I don't think the difference is measurable but it's like killing an ant with a tank. This aside, OP goal is to end up with keys starting with "A" instead of "a" and your approach won't get him there.

Comment: @ShadowWizard How do you think that string operations such as .Concat() and .Replace() are implemented in .NET? They use StringBuilders. And there is no need to call them "whole new StringBuilders". A StringBuilder is actually a pretty small object, much smaller than the string inside it. OP clearly is looking for a mutable string. That's called a StringBuilder in .NET.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten `How do you think that string operations such as .Concat() and .Replace() are implemented in .NET? They use StringBuilders.` No, you're wrong.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM I stand corrected. They were in the first version(s?) of .NET, but not any more. StringBuilder has been changed as well, it used to simply encapsulate a string and mutate it, but not any more.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Out of curiosity, I ran a benchmark. See my updated answer for results. Note that I'm not saying your solution is worse than mine, in fact I believe it has the advantage of readability for this simple case.

Comment: Congrats for all the efforts! For me StringBuilder was always something that should be used for "heavy processing", like appending thousands of strings so using it for such tiny task looked... well, what I said before. Admit my mistake regarding efficiency, but personally I'll keep using Substring and one line for sake of habit and readability.

Comment: @ShadowWizard This isn't even the fasted code. Twice as fast, half the memory usage: `unsafe { fixed (char* p = input) { string temp = new string(p, 0, input.Length); fixed (char* pt = temp) { pt[0] = 'A'; } input = temp; } }`. But don't tell anyone.

Comment: I kind of feel bad you spent so much time on this when it doesn't address the OP's goal here... but at least it's useful for others! :)